# Why does width: 100% shrink this div within a flex parent?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm not so much looking for a solution as I am trying to *understand* what is happening.

In the code below, I have a flex enabled div with two child elements.

- I explicitly set its width of the first child to 18rem.
- I set the width of the second child to 100%.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.w-72 {
  width: 18rem;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(147 197 253 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-orange-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(254 215 170 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <nav class="bg-blue-300 w-72">Nav</nav>
  <article class="w-full bg-orange-200">Article</article>
</div>
```

[image]

I *thought* this would expand the `<article>` to fill the remaining horizontal width, but it actually causes the width of the neighboring `<nav>` to shrink. (Try running this code with and without `w-full` to see for yourself.)

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default setting on a flex container is [`flex-shrink: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink#formal_definition). This means that flex items will automatically shrink to avoid overflowing the container.

To force flex items to respect their defined lengths, you must disable `flex-shrink`.

Add this to your code:

```
.w-72 {
  width: 18rem;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
}
```

(The equivalent shorthand for the code above would be `flex: 0 0 18rem`.)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.w-72 {
  width: 18rem;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* NEW */
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(147 197 253 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-orange-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(254 215 170 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <nav class="bg-blue-300 w-72">Nav</nav>
  <article class="w-full bg-orange-200">Article</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because flex always compromises widths when there are conflicts. It cannot both make the right side `100%` and the left side `18rem` so it cuts the same amount out of both to make them both fit. For example, if you were to have two items in a flex box, and each one is set to `width: 60%`, the *working* width of each item will be `50%`, because flex will shave `10%` off each side to make them both fit. To fix this, you can specify a `min-width` which is much more powerful than `width` by itself.

However, the *correct* way to have an item fill the remaining space in a flexbox is to use `flex: 1` *instead* of using width, as shown below.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.w-72 {
  width: 18rem;
}

.w-full {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(147 197 253 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-orange-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(254 215 170 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <nav class="bg-blue-300 w-72">Nav</nav>
  <article class="w-full bg-orange-200">Article</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Applying the `w-full` class to the  element causes it to have a width: 100%, while the  element has a fixed width of 18rem. Since the total available space is limited, flex distributes the available space proportionally, causing both elements to shrink so they fit within the container.

Using `flex: 1` is the correct way to make an item fill the remaining space in a flex container, allow it to grow and occupy the available space proportionally, and not have an effect on the width of other elements.

This should work:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.w-72 {
  width: 18rem;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(147 197 253 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-orange-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(254 215 170 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

<div class="flex">
  <nav class="bg-blue-300 w-72">Nav</nav>
  <article class="flex-grow bg-orange-200">Article</article>
</div>
```